# Dúvida sobre SQL - Group by (iniciante)

Tags: sql, query, group-by

Tenho duas tabelas, uma com nomes de médicos e outra com as classificações does atendimentos e quero listar os médicos e as quantidades de atendimentos com base nas classificações. Pra isso fiz o seguinte query:

```sql
Select
    a.TabAtendimentoSaida->TabMedicoId->TabPrestador->Codigo as CRM,
    a.TabAtendimentoSaida->TabMedicoId->TabPrestador->Nome as Médico,
    Case b.Prioridade->Cor
        When '$00FF8000' Then 'AZUL'
        When '$0000FF00' Then 'VERDE'
        When '$0000FFFF' Then 'AMARELO'
        When '$00FF00FF' Then 'SEM CLASSIFICADOR'
        When '$000080FF' Then 'LARANJA'
        When '$00000000' Then 'NÃO RESPONDEU'
        When '$000000FF' Then 'VERMELHO'
        Else Null
    End as Cor,
    Count(b.Prioridade->Cor) as Quantidade
  From
    Cliente.Atendimento a,
    WClaRisco.Classificacao b
  Where
    a.TabAtendimentoSaida->TabMedicoId->TabPrestador->Codigo = :crm;
    and a.Data between :datainicio; and :datafim;
    and a.CodigoRa = b.Atendimento->Atendimento->CodigoRa
  Group by b.Prioridade->Cor
  Order by 4 DESC
```

E a consulta vem funcionando corretamente, para me trazer médicos individualmente.
Porém, se eu quero que ela me traga mais de um médico, pela consulta ter o clause Group by, ele agrupa médicos diferentes.
Acredito que apenas um parenteses no lugar certo já faria a consulta funcionar para médicos diferentes, mas não tô conseguindo saber qual é esse "lugar certo".

Tentei acrescentar um

```
Distinct by a.TabAtendimentoSaida->TabMedicoId->TabPrestador->Codigo
```

no começo da consulta, mas está rodando já há algum tempo... Não acredito que vá funcionar.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que se acrescentar o CRM no group by ele já vá dividir de acordo com a Cor e CRM

```
Select
    a.TabAtendimentoSaida->TabMedicoId->TabPrestador->Codigo as CRM,
    a.TabAtendimentoSaida->TabMedicoId->TabPrestador->Nome as Médico,
    Case b.Prioridade->Cor
        When '$00FF8000' Then 'AZUL'
        When '$0000FF00' Then 'VERDE'
        When '$0000FFFF' Then 'AMARELO'
        When '$00FF00FF' Then 'SEM CLASSIFICADOR'
        When '$000080FF' Then 'LARANJA'
        When '$00000000' Then 'NÃO RESPONDEU'
        When '$000000FF' Then 'VERMELHO'
        Else Null
    End as Cor,
    Count(b.Prioridade->Cor) as Quantidade
  From
    Cliente.Atendimento a,
    WClaRisco.Classificacao b
  Where
    a.TabAtendimentoSaida->TabMedicoId->TabPrestador->Codigo = :crm;
    and a.Data between :datainicio; and :datafim;
    and a.CodigoRa = b.Atendimento->Atendimento->CodigoRa
  Group by b.Prioridade->Cor, a.TabAtendimentoSaida->TabMedicoId->TabPrestador->Codigo
  Order by 4 DESC
```

Comment: O problema é que o CRM deve se repetir. O resultado para consultas individuais do query deve me trazer o CRM e nome do médico para cada uma das Classificações que ele atendeu e a contagem. Se ele atendeu 5 pacientes "azuis" e 3 pacientes "amarelos", o resultado me trará duas linhas, ambas repetindo o CRM e o nome do médico e, em uma delas a quantidade de pacientes azuis e na outra a quantidade de pacientes amarelos.

Comment: Sim, mas se você acrescentar o CRM no group by ele vai dividir as informações pela cor e pelo respectivo CRM

Comment: Vou tentar rodar dessa forma. Retorno em algumas horas. Obrigado!

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado! Vou agora dar uma estudada para entender porque isso funcionou... Hahaha

Comment: é simples, o group by serve para desmembrar as operações (count, sum, avg).
Desta forma quando informa somente um campo "Cor" ele vai fazer o calculo separando somente pela cor, ao incluir mais um campo ele tera mais uma condição para realizar calculos